# What is the proper way to await an Asynchronous method in Program.Main( )?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

The following will always hang at the end :

```
namespace WhyDoesThisAlwaysHappen {
    static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main( ) {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles( );
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault( false );
            new Form1( );
            DGApp.Start( ).DontBlock( ).GetAwaiter( ).Result( );
        }
    }

    static class Extensions {
        public static async Task DontBlock( this Task T ) {
            await T.ConfigureAwait( false );
        }

        public static async Task<T> DontBlock<T>( this Task<T> T2 ) {
            return await T2.ConfigureAwait( false );
        }
    }

    static class DGApp {
        public static async Task Start( ) {
            await RegistrationTables.Instance.Initialize( ).DontBlock( );
        }
    }

    class RegistrationTables {
        private static RegistrationTables _Instance = null;
        public static RegistrationTables Instance { get { return RegistrationTables._Instance ?? ( RegistrationTables._Instance = new RegistrationTables( ) ); } }
        private SQL SQLTool;

        public async Task Initialize( ) {
            await ( this.SQLTool = new SQL( new CancellationTokenSource( ).Token ) ).ReadConnectionFile( "Foo" ).DontBlock( );
        }
    }

    class SQL {
        private CancellationToken _CT;
        public SQL( CancellationToken CT ) {
            this._CT = CT;
        }

        public async Task ReadConnectionFile( string Foo ) {
            string[ ] ConnectionDetails = await FTP.ReadFile( Foo, this._CT ).DontBlock( );
        }
    }

    static class FTP {
        public static async Task<string[ ]> ReadFile( string Foo, CancellationToken CT ) {
            await Task.Delay( 1000 ).DontBlock( );
            return new string[ ] { };
        }
    }
}
```

`Form1( )` is nothing more than a default blank form created when you create a new WinForms project.

I have discovered that if I were to comment out the line new `Form1( )` that it runs through absolutely fine, but when I leave the line in place it hangs at the final `await Task.Delay( ... );`

Why does this keep happening? What is the proper way to call an asynchronous method from `Program.Main( )`? Is it even possible?

### EDIT 1

Please note this occurs consistently regardless of the presence (or absence) of the `DontBlock( )` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an application loop, which in the winforms world, means using `Application.Run`.  That message loop will then process all asynchronous messages sent to it.  You could of course create your own message loop if you wanted to, but since you are using a winform application, you can just use theirs.

> Why does this keep happening?

Because you keep synchronously blocking the UI thread with operations that are dependant on *other* UI messages to be completed first, creating a deadlock.  You need to not synchronously block on such operations and have a message loop that you actually let process messages.

> Please note this occurs consistently regardless of the presence (or absence) of the `DontBlock()` extension.

Of course it does.  That's because you're blocking on the call to `DontBlock`, and naming a method "DontBlock" doesn't make it not block.  Your `DontBlock` method does literally nothing, other than wasting some CPU cycles creating a task that is functionally identical to the task that it takes as a parameter.  Your program would function identically if you simply removed all calls to that method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it has raised more questions. I will link in another comment if you can help me further.

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to figure it out - thanks for your help.